# android list font size changing runtime

Tags: android, listview, fonts, size

I have set the size in the list as 16 but when i run my code it is coming as 7 and the text in the list is coming very small. I tried to change the size at runtime also, but the still the size is coming small. 
If I switch between my activities 3-4 times, then its size is coming ok in the list and Which is ok for me to have the visibility. But when it is coming 7 it is very small.

Below is my code:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
View vi = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;

tempValues = null;
tempValues = (ModelLoveQuotes) data.get(position);

if (convertView == null) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_tablerow);
    float textSize1 = holder.text.getTextSize();
    Log.d(TAG,"manish text size1: "+textSize1); //this is coming 7
    vi.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    float textSize2 = holder.text.getTextSize();
    Log.d(TAG,"manish text size2: "+textSize2); //this is coming 7
}
boolean favExist = false;
if (al_favSMS != null) {
    for (ModelFavoriteSMS favSms : al_favSMS) {
        if (favSms.getMesssage().equalsIgnoreCase(tempValues.getBody())) {
            favExist = true;
            break;
        } else {
            favExist = false;
        }
    }
}
if (favExist) {
    holder.image1 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    holder.image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black);
} else {
    holder.image1 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    holder.image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black);
}
if (data.size() <= 0) {
    holder.text.setText("No Data");
} else {
    holder.text.setMaxLines(2);
    holder.text.setText(tempValues.getBody());
    holder.image1.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
}
return vi;
```

}

tabitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_trans"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="60dp">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tablerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16sp" <!-- I have defined it 16sp here -->
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black"
                android:tag="fav"

                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I marked the places where the value is coming 7 and where I have defined it 16sp.

Comment: I tried to set a larger value like 40, so initially the font size is coming 17 but after moving between different activities its size increase to 44 and font become very large. Not understanding the font is changing at runtime while i have defined it in the xml in static way.

Comment: I have updated the places where is it is coming 7 and where I have defined it 16. There is no other place where I am changing its value in the code. Still the value is not coming correct. I am stuck with this problem from a very long time and not able to fine the solution. If you need any further information in regard to this please let me know. Thanks in Advance..